# Counting across multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, count, multiple-columns

I'm pretty new to Python and have searched the web for an answer to this but it is tricky to find without showing it as an example!

The data I have data is here:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGQtp.jpg)

What I'm after is the number of times each 'HomeTeam' has appeared in both the 'HomeTeam' and 'AwayTeam' columns up to and including the date. So for the last row of data in the sample, the input would be 'Fulham', and the output = 4. This is because 'Fulham' has appeared 4 times in the 'HomeTeam' and 'AwayTeam' columns. For the first row of data, again, the input would be 'Fulham', but the output = 1, as it is the first time 'Fulham' has appeared. For the sample dataset, the output should be:

```
[1,1,2,1,3,1,4]
```

My code so far only allows me to get the number of times each team has appeared in the 'HomeTeam' column only:

```
df['H Count'] =  df.groupby(['HomeTeam']).cumcount()+1
```

This gives me the output:

```
[1,1,1,1,2,1,2]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: I think for all sample data, what is `H Count` column

Comment: The H Count column is where the desired output will go...so for the first row of data where Fulham are the Home Team, the 'H Count' for Fulham will be 1 as they have appeared once in the HomeTeam and AwayTeam columns.

Comment: For the bottom row of data, the 'H Count' for Fulham will be 4, as they have appeared 4 times in the HomeTeam and AwayTeam columns.

Comment: So input is `Fulham` and output ... ?

Comment: oops, I think `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]`

Comment: Each Home Team is the input, with their output being the number of times they appear in the HomeTeam and AwayTeam columns up to and including the date of the row. So the output should be [1,1,2,1,3,1,4]...e.g. the 3rd value = 2 because Aston Villa have featured twice in the list. Sorry for the poor explanation!

Comment: I am now confused... Can you give me all data otput from your sample data in question?

Comment: Because I dont understand logic - how I know what teams are count in column?

Comment: I've edited the question now so hopefully it should be a bit clearer!

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Sure - I've added it to the main question.

Comment: how about `HomeTeam.count(yourInput) + HomeTeam.count(yourInput)`

Comment: Would that give me the cumulative count of the number of times each team appears though?

Comment: I would write it differently but using your code, isn't your solution just, df['H Count'] = df.groupby(['HomeTeam']).cumcount()+df.groupby(['AwayTeam']).cumcount() + 1

Comment: @BryanZeng.. should be ...+ AwayTeam.count(yourInput) no?

Comment: @niCkcAMel ..I think doing it that way gives me the number of times the away team has appeared the 'AwayTeam' column, added to the number of times the home team appears in the 'HomeTeam' column, rather than the number of times the home team appears in both columns!

Comment: @bobman - I count it again and  get `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]`.  Why do you get last 2 `1` in your output `[1,1,2,1,3,1,4]` ?

Comment: @jezrael ..the output for the 2nd last = 1 because 'Leeds' is the input from the 'HomeTeam' column, and this is 'Leeds'' first appearance in the dataset, so the output = 1.

Comment: But there is `Fulham`, it is not count?

Comment: @jezrael .. so for each row, I am only interested in the number of times the string in the 'HomeTeam' column appears up to that date. So for the last row, because 'Fulham' is the input, and 'Fulham' appears 4 times in the dataset, the last output value = 4. But the second last one, the input is 'Leeds', who are there once.

Comment: I think @Bryan Zeng comment above have already answered this question, with slight modification `HomeTeam.count(yourInput) + AwayTeam.count(yourInput)`

Comment: @niCkcAMel Thanks, I forgot to delete the thing while copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, the team currently in the HomeTeam is being used as input.
I don't know how you read in the dataset, but I have just created lists below. The logic should however be clear.
Having the below, I get `[1, 1, 3]`

```
HomeTeam = list()
HomeTeam.append("Fulham")
HomeTeam.append("Tottenham")
HomeTeam.append("Fulham")
AwayTeam = list()
AwayTeam.append("Chelsea")
AwayTeam.append("Fulham")
AwayTeam.append("Liverpool")
H_Count = []

p = 1
''' The team in the HomeTeam is used as input'''
for team in HomeTeam:
    ''' Get the list up until the current row'''
    tmp_Home = HomeTeam[:p]
    tmp_Away = AwayTeam[:p]

    ''' Count the number of times team has occured in home and away'''
    H_Count.append(tmp_Home.count(team) + tmp_Away.count(team))

    p+=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - think the problem was that I was trying to use Pandas as the data was in dataframe format, but your way seems a lot simpler!

Comment: @bobman ok, if you have a specific question regarding Pandas, you should specify it in your question. If you think this is the answer to the question as it is now you can accept it. Otherwise comment why you don't think this answers your question. Good luck

Comment: Haha first time using stackoverflow! Think I've managed to do it!